# Saving Values from ExcelDataReader DataSets

Tags: c#, excel, dataset

I'm using C# to read an Excel file using `ExcelDataReader` and `ExcelDataReader.DataSet`. I'm not too familiar with parsing DataSets so I was wondering how to save the values from each row in a particular column in the Excel. I need the code to pull all the values from the first column of the spreadsheet I load.

```
public void ExcelFileReader(string path)
{
    var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);
    var rowCount = reader.RowCount;

    result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
    {
        ConfigureDataTable = (DataTableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
        {
            UseHeaderRow = true
        }
    });

    var tables = result.Tables.Cast<DataTable>();
    var dataTable = result.Tables[0].Columns[0].ToString();
    foreach(DataTable table in tables)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }
}
```

The line: `var dataTable = result.Tables[0].Columns[0].ToString();` will get me the name of the header for the column I want but how do I parse through the rows of column 1 and save all the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate throught the rows of the table and then get the column 0 value.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row[0]);
}
```

This will write all the values from the first column (index 0).

Comment: That solved it! Thanks so much!